# Pyspark: Convert bigint to timestamp with microseconds

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert a `bigint` unix timestamp to the following `datetime` format `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSSSSS"` to include microseconds.
When I use the standard to datetime function I get the following

```
spark.sql("select to_timestamp(1605509165022529) as ts").show(truncate=False)
```

Result

```
+----------------------------+
|ts                          |
+----------------------------+
|22327-10-26 13:09:588.009408|
+----------------------------+
```

This `datetime` is wrong. The date should be 2020-11-16 with the time in `HH:mm:ss:SSSSSS`.

How can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide your timestamp by 1e6 because `to_timestamp` expects a unix timestamp in units of second, not microsecond.

```
spark.sql("select to_timestamp(1605509165022529/1e6) as ts").show(truncate=False)

+--------------------------+
|ts                        |
+--------------------------+
|2020-11-16 06:46:05.022529|
+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

This will let you convert directly to a `micros` `timestamp` from a `unix_micros` `BigInt`. You unfortunately can't call it directly with `F.timestamp_micros()`, but you can pass it as a SQL expression.

Just in case, this is how to use `F.`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
 
sdf = sdf.withColumn('end_time', F.expr(f"timestamp_micros({'end_time'})"))
```